# Slice multidimensional numpy array from max in a given axis

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting

I have a 3-dimensional array `a` of shape `(n, m, l)`. I extract one column `j` from it's last axis and compute the maximum index along the first axis like follows:

```
sub = a[:, :, j]  # shape (n, m)
wheremax = np.argmax(sub, axis=0)  # this have a shape of m
```

Now I'd like to slice the original array `a` to get all the information based on the index where the column `j` is maximal. I.e. I'd like an *numpythonic* way to do the following using array broadcasting or numpy functions:

```
new_arr = np.zeros((m, l))
for i, idx in enumerate(wheremax):
    new_arr[i, :] = a[idx, i, :]
a = new_arr
```

Is there one?

Comment: `a[wheremax, np.arange(m)]` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hpaulj mentionned in the comments, using `a[wheremax, np.arange(m)]` did the trick.